# MySQL Stored Procedure check if table exists then Alter Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax, alter

I have stored procedure as below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST;
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT table_name 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE table_name LIKE 'User') A) > 0 THEN
        ALTER TABLE User DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_forkey
    END IF;
END

SELECT ....
```

I have the syntax error at END IF. I have been trying many ways to fix this but no success so far. If I add Delimiter // after the DROP PROCEDURE and after the END, I get error at the end Delimiter (delimiter is not valid input at this position). What did I miss/How did I do it wrong? Thank you in advance for your response.

***UPDATED***

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT table_name 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE table_name LIKE 'User')
    THEN
       ALTER TABLE User DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_AccountID;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

The updated above is my new change and it reports error at the end Delimiter: `Delimiter is not valid input at this position`

Comment: Did you miss `;` after `ALTER TABLE User DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_forkey` line?

Comment: Hi @Evgeny, thanks for your comment. I have updated my question. Please see above.

Comment: You have to leave a space between `delimiter` and `;`

Comment: What a basic error! Thanks Solarflare. Please answer below so I could mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from @Solarflare, since he/she didn't post the answer, I'll do it instead so I could mark this question as answered and it may come in handy for others newbies that might run into the same problem as me.

> You have to leave a space between delimiter and ;